# Use one line of code on 1 html page to print something from another php script

Tags: php, html

I don't really know how to ask this but here goes.

I would like to place a line of code on a web page and have it print what's in the php script that it points to. I guess like a counter does.

Here is the code I am testing but it's not working. Any help would be great!

The php file holding the html code..

```
<?php
echo<<<END
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="putform.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<input type="hidden" name="btn_submit" value="1">
<input type="text" maxlength="20" size="20" name="fname" value="" class="formfieldname" placeholder="First Name"><p />
<input type="text" maxlength="20" size="20" name="lname" value="" class="formfieldname" placeholder="Last Name"><p />
<input type="text" name="email" maxlength="55" size="20" value="" class="formfieldemail" placeholder="Best Email"><p />
<input type="text" maxlength="20" size="20" name="phone" value="" class="formfieldphone" placeholder="Cell Phone"><p />
<p />
<input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="SHOW ME THE FREE TRAINING">
<input type="hidden" name="affiliate" value="$affiliate">
<input type="hidden" name="myip" value="$myip">
<input type="hidden" name="c" value="$id">
<input type="hidden" name="program_id" value="$id">
<input type="hidden" name="campaign" value="$campaign">
<input type="hidden" name="campaignid" value="$campaignid">
</form> 
END;
?>
```

Here is a sample of the HTML code that someone would visit...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- this will be replaced with the form html code -->
<script src="example.com/test_form.php"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the 2nd Script is a PHP File, you can simply use require_once to fetch it (since in the PHP File holding the HTML Code, you are already echoing some Data). Here is how:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>test</title>
        </head>
        <body>

        <!-- this will be replaced with the form html code -->
        <?php require_once "example.com/test_form.php"; ?>

        </body>
    </html>
```

You may simply configure your Server (APACHE) to treat Files with .html extension as regular PHP Files. Here is how: if you don't have a .htaccess File in your Project root, create it. Then inside the .htaccess File add the following line:

```
    # TELLS APACHE TO HANDLE ALL FILES WITH .html or .htm EXTENSIONS AS PHP FILES.
    AddHandler x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

However, depending on your Server, the above may not work; in which case you may may try one of the following:

```
    # TELLS APACHE TO HANDLE ALL FILES WITH .html or .htm EXTENSIONS AS PHP FILES.
    AddHandler php-script .php .html .htm
```

or this:

```
    # TELLS APACHE TO HANDLE ALL FILES WITH .html or .htm EXTENSIONS AS PHP FILES.
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

However, the first variant may most likely work for you. Hopefully; this helps. Good Luck to you, my Friend.

Comment: I like that idea but it will be end users using the code so my question would be.... Can you add <?php code ?> to any HTML file and it work or will the end user have to be sure they have something in their .htaccess file? I need it to be very simple for the end user. This will allow them to place an optin form on their own website but the form will point to my database for them. Kind of like aweber does for it's members.

Comment: @RandyThomas Yes you can.... check out the updated post and see how that goes... however you need to do that in your .htaccess File...

Answer (score 0):

To have ability use php variables you probably should do like this:

```
$myVar = <<<END
// your html here with $campaign and $campaignId
END;

$search = ['$campaign', '$campaignId', ...];
$replace = [$campaign, $campaignId, ...]
$final = str_replace($search, $replace, $myVar);
```

and use `require_once();` in your html file.